# multiple orderby linq query with booleans

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, tuples

lets say I have a list of CustomObjects such that

```
List<CustomObject> list = new List<CustomObject>();
public class CustomObject
{
    public int page {get;set;}
    public bool configured {get;set;}
    public bool searchable {get;set;}
    <more bool properties>
}
```

and I want to be able to sort or filter by these boolean values. But not all of the properties are required. so, some are nullable. I would like to build a dynamic query that simply chains together OrderBy() and ThenBy()
I thought maybe I should create a tuple to help.

```
List<Tuple<string, bool>> expressionTuple = new List<Tuple<string, bool>>();
// so now I have a list of tuples.
// so based on whether or not my method parameters are null or not I populate the list
if(ShouldFilter(methodParameter))
{
   expressionTuple.Add(new Tuple<string, bool>("ColumnName", methodParameter)));
}
```

So I was thinking about some kind of chanined custom sort function like so:

```
private IEnumerable<T> CustomSort<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, List<Tuple<string, bool>> sortExpression)
{ 
     for(int i = 0; i < sortExpression.Count; i++)
     {
         int index = i; // see if this is the first iteration
         // build an expression that would be similar to:
         if(index==0)
         {
             data = list.OrderBy(x=>x.ColumnName == booleanValue);
         }else
         {
             data = list.ThenBy(x=>x.ColumnNam == booleanValue);
         }
      }
  }
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this. maybe there is an easier way??

Comment: Expression trees can do this.

Comment: Maybe this will be of help to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Comment: By the way, the property names of `CustomObject` to start with upper case letters to conform with C# coding style conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why? If you're using different orderings on different places, just put the LINQ-expressions at these various places?
Seems to me like you're trying to complicate something that's not really that complicated.

```
data.OrderBy(p => p.Page)
    .ThenBy(p => p.Configured)
    .ThenBy(...);
```